# Get hierarchical data neo4jclient

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have 3 classes. They are related hierarchically. How get hiearchiacal data and union it it one class or dictionary array? I lately want insert data to treeview

3 classes

1. class Lvl1 {string name}
2. class Lvl2 {string name}
3. class Lvl3 {string name}

[image: picture of the schema]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do your queries look like to get the individual data?

Comment: i know how make simple queries - but this query is very hard/

Comment: MATCH (n:Lvl1) 
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[:HAVE_LVL2]->(s:Lvl2) RETURN n,s this code return me one rel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do:

```
MATCH (root:Lvl1)-[:HAVE_LVL2|HAVE_LVL3*0..]->(leaf)
RETURN distinct leaf
```

Comment: in which array I insert it?

Comment: this is good query, but this return only Lvl1 and Lvl2 data, no Lvl3

Comment: MATCH (n:Lvl1) OPTIONAL MATCH n-[:HAVE_LVL1]->(s)-[:HAVE_LVL2]->(x) return n,s,x;  this query is not work correct